# Which abilities can Fizz's E not avoid

Tags: league-of-legends

So I believe that the question is pretty straightforward. I would like to know which abilities can Fizz's E not avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Playful/Trickster can avoid every ability in the game but it cannot remove dots. Some abilities I know for a fact that it doesn't strip are:
    - Fiddlesticks' drain 
    - Swain's Decrepify and Torment 
    - Malzahar's space aids 
    - The dot from Casseopeia's Noxious Blast and Miasma 
    - Brand's passive (burn a target for x% of their hp) 
    - Nidalee's Bushwack (he has to step on it before he activates playful/trickster) 
    - Tristana's explosive shot active (he can dodge it while its travelling to him) 
    - Teemo's poison too!

Those are just a few that I know of and is subject to (possible) change.

Answer (score 3):

Fizz's E is very similar to Elise's rappel in this regard. Anything that is *travelling* to you can be dodged, but anything that is already on you will stay on you. You're effectively 'un-hittable', but not invulnerable.

For example, any projectiles that are on their way to you, such as a cait ult, annie q, etc, will be dodged. However a dot that is already on you, ignite, another fizz's poison, darius bleed, will continue to affect and deal damage for their full duration.

Comment: Doesn't ignite stops for the time that you are using E?
Like Fiora's R doesn't deal damage for the time you are using E.

Comment: It doesnt stop completely, rather, you can dodge a tick or two, which is likely a bug either way. Fioras R is considered 5 different strikes, rather than a dot.
See [this](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2324295) for more discussion on fizz and vlads troll pole/pool and dots

Comment: Question, Can Elise and Fizz avoid Karthus's Ult?

Comment: If timed correctly, yes.

Comment: Fizz's E avoiding Fiora's R it's not a bug. In the past it could  completely negate her ultimate but they fixed it.

Comment: Yes, its supposed to be able to dodge fioras R if timed correctly.